# How to not automatically sort my y axis bar plot in ggplot & lemon

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-lemon

I am trying to display data by Species that has different values depending on group Letter. The best way I have found to display my data is by putting my categorical data on the y-axis and displaying the Total_Observed on the x-axis. Lemon allows me to have different y-axis labels. Unfortunately, the graph sorts by my y-axis labels instead of using my data as is, which is sorted by most abundant species to least abundant. Any suggestions?

Using libraries: dplyr, ggplot2, lemon

My data:

```
|Letter |Species                  | Total_Observed|
|:------|:------------------------|--------------:|
|A      |Yellowtail snapper       |            155|
|A      |Sharksucker              |            119|
|A      |Tomtate                  |            116|
|A      |Mutton snapper           |            104|
|A      |Little tunny             |             96|
|B      |Vermilion snapper        |           1655|
|B      |Red snapper              |           1168|
|B      |Gray triggerfish         |            689|
|B      |Tomtate                  |            477|
|B      |Red porgy                |            253|
|C      |Red snapper              |            391|
|C      |Vermilion snapper        |            114|
|C      |Lane snapper             |             95|
|C      |Atlantic sharpnose shark |             86|
|C      |Tomtate                  |             73|
|D      |Lane snapper             |            627|
|D      |Red grouper              |            476|
|D      |White grunt              |            335|
|D      |Gray snapper             |            102|
|D      |Sand perch               |             50|
|E      |White grunt              |            515|
|E      |Red grouper              |            426|
|E      |Red snapper              |            150|
|E      |Black sea bass           |            142|
|E      |Lane snapper             |             88|
|E      |Gag                      |             88|
|F      |Yellowtail snapper       |            385|
|F      |White grunt              |            105|
|F      |Gray snapper             |             88|
|F      |Mutton snapper           |             82|
|F      |Lane snapper             |             59|
```

Then I run the code for my ggplot/lemon
`ggplot(test,aes(y=Species,x=Total_Observed))+geom_histogram(stat='identity')+facet_wrap(.~test$Letter,scales='free_y')`

And my graphs print like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you post your data using `dput(test)`?

Comment: You can create a factor order by total. I you need order within facets, take a look at this [blogpost](https://juliasilge.com/blog/reorder-within/) about te function `reorder_within()`

Comment: Thank you Johan for that very useful resource. That blog had the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Johan Rosa's shared blog (https://juliasilge.com/blog/reorder-within/): The solution is to use the library(tidytext). With the functions reorder_within and scale_x_reordered.

The corrected code:
`test %>% mutate(Species=reorder_within(Species,Total_Observed,Letter)) %>% ggplot(aes(Species,Total_Observed))+geom_histogram(stat='identity')+facet_wrap(~Letter,scales='free_y')+coord_flip()+scale_x_reordered()`

Will now generate the graphs ordered correctly
[image]